# String in multiple lines in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I how i make string in multiple lines in VS2010 and using C#. I have a HTML markup as a string and it is filling in a code behind(cs) as in the designer page(aspx). How to i make it in one line or which  character i have to put at the end of line so that string will be concatenating next lines. Below is the string sample.

```
 string text="<table> <tr> <td> <table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\"  style=\"mso-cellspacing: 1.5pt; mso-border-alt: outset black .75pt; mso-yfti-tbllook: 1184; 
        mso-padding-alt: 1.5pt 1.5pt 1.5pt 1.5pt; height: 264px; width: 100%;  font-size: 10.0pt; border: 1.0pt outset black; font-family: Times New Roman, serif; \"> 
            <tr style=\"mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes\">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) for this - they are declared by using a `@` before the string declaration. The `"` escape on those is `""`.

```
string text= @"<table> <tr> <td> <table border=""1"" cellpadding=""0""  style=""mso-cellspacing: 1.5pt; mso-border-alt: outset black .75pt; mso-yfti-tbllook: 1184; 
    mso-padding-alt: 1.5pt 1.5pt 1.5pt 1.5pt; height: 264px; width: 100%;  font-size: 10.0pt; border: 1.0pt outset black; font-family: Times New Roman, serif; ""> 
        <tr style=""mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes"">";
```

Comment: @eraj - `\"` is the escape for _regular_ strings. You need to use `""` for verbatim strings.

Comment: Thanks its working for me. More over if i want to insert some variable string in between. How can we write this.

Comment: @eraj - I suggest using `string.Format` with [composite format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add a @ in front of the first "

like this:
string text = @"This
is on

multiple
lines";